# Why can't I iterate a (multiprocessing) manager list?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have an array consisting of manager lists like:

```
[<ListProxy object, typeid 'list' at 0x177d350>, <ListProxy object, typeid 'list' at 0x177d390>, ...]
```

and try to convert it to a pure list. My consideration looks like:

```
y=[]
for i in my_manager_list_content:
    for j in i:
        y.append(float(j))
print y #This works

print [next(iter(i[:]))  for i in my_manager_list_content] #Why doesn't this work?
```

How could I do this in a oneliner?

Comment: `[float(i) for j in my_manager_list_content for i in j]`?

Comment: Thank you. That's the solution!

Answer (score 2):

Explanation on why your codes don't work. `iter()` takes an iterable object and returns an interator. `next()` takes the iterator and returns the next element. In your code, when you take an element out of your `my_manager_list_content`, you only get the first element out of it with `next` and then you move on the the second element of the `my_manager_list_content`. This can be illustrated by the codes below: (an expansion on @Kevin Guan 's solution)

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Manager

def f(ll, l):
    for ii in range(3):
        ll.append(l)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Manager() as manager:
        ll = manager.list()
        l = manager.list(range(3))
        p = Process(target=f, args=(ll, l))
        p.start()
        p.join()

        print([float(ii) for jj in ll for ii in jj])
        print([next(iter(ii)) for ii in ll])
```

And I get

```
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0]
[0, 0, 0]
```